# TensorFlow：How to generate differentiable mask

Tags: python, tensorflow, mask

I want to generate a mask from a tensor. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
input = tf.Variable(np.array([[0, 0.1], [0.9, 1.0]]))
```

And from `input`, I want to get a mask tensor with value:

```
[[0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0]]
```

A way to do this is:

```
output = tf.cast(tf.cast(input, dtype=tf.bool), dtype=tf.float32)
```

However, `tf.cast` is not differentiable and the gradient can not back-propagate while I hope that the operation is differentiable. 
I also search other methods such as `tf.floor`, `tf.where` but they are all not differentiable.

A possible method is to use these undifferentiable methods and define the gradient for them. However, I wonder what their gradients should be in order to make the back-propagation feasible (maybe just set the gradient to be 1 ?) and why?

Answer (score 2):

As you suggested, you can artificially stick a gradient to a masking operation that is not differentiable. Here is an example, where the gradient is always one:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def my_mask(x):
  return tf.to_float(tf.greater(x, 0))

def diff_mask(mask_op):
  @tf.custom_gradient
  def _diff_mask(x):
    def grad(dy):
      return dy * tf.ones_like(x)
    return mask_op(x), grad
  return _diff_mask

x = tf.random_normal((5,))
w = tf.random_normal((5,))
m = diff_mask(my_mask)(w)
loss = x * m
g = tf.gradients([loss], [x, w])

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run([x, loss] + g)
```

You could of course choose another gradient, for example the gradient of the sigmoid. It really depends on what you want to do; any choice will be wrong since thresholding is not differentiable, but hopefully one choice will be useful for you.

A pitfall of this kind of technique is that now the gradient that you use is not the gradient of the loss you are minimizing. That is why people generally tends to use soft thresholds, rather than hard threshold. For example if you intend to use the gradient of the sigmoid because you feel you need a threshold in the feedback, then why not using the sigmoid itself as a mask?

Comment: Thanks! I want to get a 2D mask of an object in the input image, and then use the mask to calculate loss. The 2D image contains some incorrect shading information so I can only use a binary mask of the image. This is why I need hard threshold.

Comment: Also, `@tf.custom_gradient` is a TensorFlow 1.7 feature and seem to require Eager mode. Is there any example of earlier version such as TF-1.3 ? Thanks!

Comment: It does not require eager mode -- my example is running in the standard, graph-based fashion. But it does require TF 1.7 or greater.